# How to target latest minor Azure Function Runtime Version locally?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

What do I have to do to get the latest Function Runtime Version running locally?

I'm developing isolated v4 app with .NET 6. Version 4.15.0 was released a week ago. [Source](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases?q=4.&expanded=true). But when I run the project, it is using v4.13.0.19486.
I've tried to explicitly set the version in app settings with the FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION setting with no success. Updated Azure Functions Core Tools and VS to the latest version. Not sure what more I have to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Late answer, but it turned out that had to wait until Functions Core Tools gets updated with the Function Runtime Version included and update Functions Core Tools.

Answer (score 0):

The local version would be the one that is part of the local version of Azure Functions Tools. The best way to test a particular minor version would be to use the docker container for the same.

[Here](https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated/tags/list) are the tags available for you to choose from.